# ckeditor don't preview picture tag

Tags: 8

i'm working on drupal 8 and i'm using picture instead of imag tags. To take the benefit of the responsivness feature. I'm just facing and issue that CKeditor can't preview the pisture tag. Any idea how to fix it ? [image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In order to achieve this you would have to enable support of `<picture>` in your text format. You can do it as below:

1. Goto `/admin/config/content/formats` path and configure the text format you are using in your field.
2. Find the checkbox option `Limit allowed HTML tags and correct faulty HTML` and check it.
3. Scroll down and find the text area where **allowed html tags** are listed.
4. Add your tag `<picture>` here along with additional attribute. For example, if you want to add class attribute to your picture tag just add `<picture class>` in allowed html tags

Comment: thanks ! i added the tags baut it doesn't worked. I just noticed that the picture tag <img> tag inside besides the <source> tags within my pages. but its not there within the wisywig. Tust the source tags. If i add that <img> by the inspector it works. Any idea how i can add it ?

Comment: You can add img tag in allowed html tags then along with attributes you want in it.